# Non null-terminated string reading standard input (Assembly Language)

Tags: assembly, filesystems, nasm, null-terminated

I'm working on making a standard library from scratch in assembly language using NASM. I'm not doing this to use it in huge project, but just to train myself with assembly language making a project that I can put on GitHub.

Anyway, I'm facing something strange with the `SYS_READ` syscall. When I type a string in the standard input and I try to create a file with it as filename, it creates the file with some strange characters after it.

[image: weird filename behavior]

As you can see, I'm trying to create a `Hello.txt` file. The program was able to do so, but it added a dollar sign and a line return. I don't know why. I reserved 10 bytes in the `.bss` section as my filename buffer, and I'm only using 8 bytes of it. I tried to use the full length and more to see what happened.

**BUT**, when I use GDB to see what's happening, there is not trace of a `$` symbol. I don't know where it comes from :
[image: gdb]

When I'm only using the full length, the file is made without weird symbols. When I use more, it acts the same, but with an overflow on the console (obviously).

I'm working on a 64bits Windows Subsystem Linux. The repo is at this address : https://github.com/Ximaz/nasm-stdlib . The issue I'm facing is stored into the `main.asm` file, at the root of the project, and all functions used are into the `stdlib` folder. I'm trying to not use libc functions such as scanf or else, because I want to do it from scratch + this issue can help me to learn more that I think.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not removing the terminating end of line from the input. Also you are ignoring the actual length of the input which is bad practice.

Comment: I don't know how to remove the terminating end of line from the input. What do you mean by ignoring the actual length of the input ?

Comment: The system call returns the number of bytes actually read. You should use that to check the last character. If it's a newline, remove it. If it's not a newline that means the user provided longer input so handle that, e.g. by printing an error message. The `$` is not in the filename, the `$'\n'` is shell syntax for a newline, it's only shown like that by your `ls`.

Comment: Next time, do not post pictures of text!  Instead copy/paste the text itself directly into your question.  Use a `<pre>` block if appropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure that posting gdb result as code would be a greater idea. here, it's more visuable, same thing with my prompt's output. I would agree if I posted a screen of assembly code, but those screens aren't code.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) :

I didn't notice that the stdin call returned the read bytes into `rax`, which is what I need to put a termination byte. Since the string contains the `\n`, I had to decrement it before puting the null byte at the `\n` position.

Comment: Note that a `read` system call doesn't guarantee that the input will end with a `\n`, even if it comes from the terminal.  A user can submit input with the EOF key (control-d by default) instead of EOL (end-of-line = newline).  Try it by running `cat` on a terminal. (And maybe attach `strace -p $(pidof cat)` to it in another terminal window).  But for toy programs, sure, safe enough to just blindly chop off one character from the input without checking that it's a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I'm going to search on how to correctly crop the string if it's not a ``\n``  string, because it's a toy project, sure, but I want to make it right as much as I can. I appreciate it.

Comment: Check if last byte of the read (`[rsi+rax-1]` ) is a `\n`, and if so overwrite it.  If not, overwrite the byte after that.  (Make sure your buffer is big enough that there's room for a terminator after read returns the full number of bytes you passed it.)

Comment: Wow, I wan't expecting an answer, but any thanks for the help. I'm going to try to implement it right now. :-)